# Can't use intel mkl in JNI shared library

Tags: java, java-native-interface, intel-mkl

I am attempting to build C JNI code that uses Intel MKL for matrix multiplication

In my C file I have

```
#include "mkl.h"
...
cblas_dgemm (CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, numRows, numCols, numRows, 1.0, mulMatrix, numRows, first, numCols, 0.0, second, numCols);
```

I compile the jni file with:

```
m082166@mforgehn4 $ icc -mkl -openmp -O3 -fPIC -std=c99 -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/linux/" -o irl/libjniconverge.so -shared c_src/MyJNICode.c
```

I had weird issues with System.loadLibrary, so I have the following code in a static initializer:

```
    String      path = System.getProperty ("jni.library");
    String[]    paths = path.split (":");

    for (String libPath : paths)
        System.load (libPath);
```

The code fails to run:

The unsurmountable error is this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_avx2.so: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_avx2.so: **undefined symbol: mkl_dft_fft_fix_twiddle_table_32f**

A post [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3884) claims that is provided by libmkl_core.so, but adding /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_core.so (24 MB) doesn't solve the problem

```
$ java -Djni.library="/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so:/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so:/home/mayo/m082166/irl/libjniconverge.so" -jar MyJava-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so: undefined symbol: mkl_dft_fft_fix_twiddle_table_32f
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at MyJava.<clinit>(MyJava.java:77)
$ java -Djni.library="/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so:/home/mayo/m082166/irl/libjniconverge.so" -jar MyJava-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin
$ java -Djni.library="/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so:/home/mayo/m082166/irl/libjniconverge.so" -jar MyJava-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so: libintlc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at MyJava.<clinit>(MyJava.java:77)
$ find /usr/local/intel-2016 -name libintlc.so
/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libintlc.so
/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/ia32_lin/libintlc.so
/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin_mic/libintlc.so
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin"
$ java -Djni.library="/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so:/home/mayo/m082166/irl/libjniconverge.so" -jar MyJava-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.
$ find /usr/local/intel-2016 -name libmkl_def.so
/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin
$ java -Djni.library="/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so:/usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so:/home/mayo/m082166/irl/libjniconverge.so" -jar MyJava-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_def.so: undefined symbol: mkl_dft_fft_fix_twiddle_table_32f
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at MyJava.<clinit>(MyJava.java:77)
```

How do I get this to link and run?

Comment: It looks like your code can't find shared library it depends on. Take a look here for a simple sample, where shared lib is used from within JNI: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_avx2.so: /usr/local/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_avx2.so: undefined symbol: mkl_dft_fft_fix_twiddle_table_32f
Supposedly this is in libmkl_core.so See: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3884 But loading libmkl_core.so doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

export LD_PRELOAD=[Path]/libmkl_def.so:[Path]/libmkl_avx2.so:[Path]/libmkl_core.so:[Path]/libmkl_intel_lp64.so:[Path]/libmkl_intel_thread.so:[Different Path]/libiomp5.so

Declare that before running the Java, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass code to `JNI`, you are no longer inside JVM (in terms of `java.library.path`). It means that any shared library loaded by your `JNI` code will load libraries using system calls.

For you, it means you have to make sure that all libraries are visible either via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or are linked using `-rpath`.

Make sure `libmkl_core.so` and libraries it depends on

```
ldd libmkl_core.so
```

are visible to your code.

Comment: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH has the directories containing all the files, but it doesn't work.  Thank you for the thought